# Write join query with groupby in Scala ActiveRecord

Tags: scala, join, activerecord, group-by

I am trying to write a specific query in [scala Active record](https://github.com/aselab/scala-activerecord). But it always returns nothing. I have read the wiki on the github page but it does not contain a lot of info on it. The query I am trying to write is

```
SELECT e.name, e.id, COUNT(pt.pass_id) as pass_count, e.start_date, e.total_passes_to_offer
FROM events e inner join passes p on e.id = p.event_id inner join pass_tickets pt on p.id = pt.pass_id where e.partner_id = 198 group by e.name, e.id
```

What I have tried is

```
Event.joins[Pass, PassTicket](
                (event, pass, passTicket) => (event.id === pass.eventId, pass.id === passTicket.passId)
            ).where(
                (event, _, _) => event.partnerId === partnerId
            ).select(
                (event, pass, _) => (event.name, event.id, PassTicket.where(_.passId === pass.id).count, event.startDate, event.totalPassesToOffer)
            ).groupBy( data => data._2)
```

But first, the return type becomes a map, not a list. And second when executed, it doesnt return anything even though the data exists. When running the SQL query directly against the database, the expected results return.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mcve]--cut & paste & runnable code plus desired output plus clear specification & explanation. Lack of one is reason to be closed. Unfortunately a defect in the bounty system is that questions with an open bounty cannot be closed. But to maximize your chances of getting a useful answer, please edit accordingly. PS What does "the SQL executes fine" mean since you don't get what you expect? PS What github page?

Comment: I would try replacing this part, with the `passTicket` ignored `(event, pass, _) => (event.name, event.id, PassTicket.where(_.passId === pass.id).count, event.startDate, event.totalPassesToOffer)` with the actual reference, something like this `(event, pass, passTicket) => (event.name, event.id, passTicket.where(_.passId === pass.id).count, event.startDate, event.totalPassesToOffer)`. I don't know if it's the correct syntax, that's why I posted a comment and not an answer.

Comment: @Shikkou that "passTicket" is only a table structure. So you cannot call methods on it.

Answer (score 4):

`scala-activerecord` dsl is based on [`squeryl`](https://squeryl.github.io/), so when figuring out a complicated query we could drop down to squeryl level and use its [`statement`](https://github.com/squeryl/squeryl/blob/3ade79142026165f81cd2def2b0b6f4c2ca1c093/src/main/scala/org/squeryl/Query.scala#L33) facility for pretty printing an SQL statment. This way we could iteratively tweek the dsl until we get the desired SQL statement. For example, say we have the following schema:

```
object Tables extends ActiveRecordTables {
  val persons = table[Person]
  val tickets = table[Ticket]
}

case class Person(name: String, email: String, age: Int) extends ActiveRecord
case class Ticket(price: Float, priority: Boolean) extends ActiveRecord {
  lazy val person = belongsTo[Person]
}

object Person extends ActiveRecordCompanion[Person]
object Ticket extends ActiveRecordCompanion[Ticket]
```

and we drop to squeryl dsl to define the following query

```
  val query =
    dsl.join(Person.toQuery, Ticket.toQuery)((person, ticket) =>
      groupBy(person.name, person.age)
      compute(count(ticket.id))
      on(person.id === ticket.id)
    )
```

then we could pretty print the statement using

```
println(Person.inTransaction(query.statement))
```

which outputs actual SQL statement

```
Select
  q1.people6_name as g0,
  q1.people6_age as g1,
  count(q7.tickets11_id) as c0
From
(Select
   people6.name as people6_name,
   people6.email as people6_email,
   people6.age as people6_age,
   people6.id as people6_id
 From
   people people6
)  q1
 inner join (Select
   tickets11.priority as tickets11_priority,
   tickets11.price as tickets11_price,
   tickets11.id as tickets11_id
 From
   tickets tickets11
)  as q7 on (q1.people6_id = q7.tickets11_id)
Group By
  q1.people6_name,
  q1.people6_age
```

Once we figure out the correct dsl in squeryl, then we at least know it is possible, and then we could attempt to write it also in scala-activerecord. Potential advantage of this approach is that squerly seems to have more documentation. Note what it states on [Group and Aggregate Queries](https://squeryl.github.io/docs/0.9.5/group-and-aggregate.html) which should indirectly also hold true for scala-activerecord:

> Squeryl diverges slightly from SQL in that **aggregate functions are not
>   allowed within a select**. They are instead declared in a ‘compute’
>   clause which is in fact a select in disguise, since it’s arguments end
>   up in the generated SQL’s select clause. The motivation for this
>   design choice is to make it a bit harder to write invalid Select
>   statements, since the **DSL forces a ‘compute’ clause to either replace
>   a select or to follow a groupBy.**

From my understanding, this means we should not write `PassTicket.where(_.passId === pass.id).count` in the `select` clause.

Regarding `groupBy` returning a `Map`, we could call `values.toList` on it to get the list back, for example, say we have

```
  Person("Picard", "picard@starfleet.org", 34).save
  Person("Data", "data@starfleet.org", 40).save
  Person("Geordi", "geordi@starfleet.org", 40).save
```

then `println(Person.groupBy(person => person.age).values.toList)` should give

```
List(
  List(Person(Data,data@starfleet.org,40), Person(Geordi,geordi@starfleet.org,40)), 
  List(Person(Picard,picard@starfleet.org,34))
)
```